# How to save registers in VIM

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I am new to VIM and I use the command

```
qa
```

to start recording the operations in register `a` and the following command

```
q
```

to stop saving. And the following command to use the operations in `a`:

```
@a
```

But the problem is that, when I close the VIM, all these registers are deleted. Is there any way to save these operations and use it later in other sessions of VIM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't run Vim in *compatible* mode (only masochists would run Vim in compatible mode), named registers, `"a` to `"z`, are remembered across sessions.

Do you run Vim without a `~/.vimrc`? What is the output of `:set viminfo`? `:set compatible?` (with the question mark)?

Comment: So… what was the problem?

Comment: I didn't have ~/.vimrc in face

Comment: Creating a blank `~/.vimrc` should be enough to make it work in "nocompatible" mode and remember your registers across sessions.

Comment: I don't think it was compatible mode! I think vim does not store macros before you save/close the file!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `map` in your `.vimrc`

```
map <F2> [your macro]
```

If the macro is already at register 'a', you can also use it, that is, instead of repeating `[your macro]`, you can type `<C-r>a` while in insert mode.

You could also try [marvim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2154).