# How to save and sync vim registers (macros)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How do I save and sync vim registers? I'm interested in macros, but I know macros are saved to registers, so that's what needs to be sync'd.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860586/how-to-save-registers-in-vim) seemed to assume that we only ever use vim with one workstation, while I need to sync to many.

I've tried to install [marvim](https://github.com/chamindra/marvim) without success.  But I wonder if there's another project or way to accomplish it, and if anyone has advice on syncing between many servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your macros in your `vimrc` as described in [this quesion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/save-a-macro-just-created-in-vimrc) on vim stackexchange. That is also suggested in one of the answer of [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860586/how-to-save-registers-in-vim). Then you sync your `vimrc` to all the servers you want with `git` as described e.g. in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232925/vim-what-the-best-practice-to-sync-up-all-plugins-on-multiple-hosts) or use any other tool of your preference.

Comment: @Polo if this answer is correct for your problem, could you mark it as correct? see [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for further information.

Comment: This works. I was hoping for more automation, but it's the best solution I've been successful with.